# Issue during scipy installation

Tags: python, scipy, pip

During the following command

```
pip install scipy
```

I get the following error

> Command "c:\users\yosief\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file_
>   _='C:\Users\yosief\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-eh0en8qk\scipy\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__fil
>   e**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\yosi
>   ef\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-v1ufkvhy-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with
>   error code 1 in C:\Users\yosief\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-eh0en8qk\scipy\

Is anybody getting this error in piping scipy?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use Anaconda which will handle your configuration issues.
It does install scipy and many useful packages on default while installation.
If does not do so..
-Just to go to the environment tab from Anaconda Navigator.
-Search your required package.
-It will fetch all dependent packages and then apply your changes.

Hope this helps..